# default ttf font for all components programmatically

Tags: java, codenameone

I am trying to set the default font programmatically but it seems to have no effect. How do I programmatically change the default font?

I have tried this:

```
        def=Font.createTrueTypeFont("Shojumaru", "Shojumaru-Regular.ttf").derive(fis.display_faktor(80), Font.STYLE_PLAIN);
    UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("Label").setFont(def);
    Display.getInstance().getCurrent().refreshTheme();
```

I have also tried this with no effect:

```
Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
h.put("font", largeFont);
UIManager.getInstance().addThemeProps(h);
Display.getInstance().getCurrent().refreshTheme();
```

Comment: This looks like Java, so I added the `java` tag. If it is wrong, please remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second syntax should work in general but it won't override all the components since if a specific component defines the font in the native theme that would be picked.

You also need to override selected/pressed/disabled fonts by using:

```
h.put("sel#font", largeFont);
h.put("press#font", largeFont);
h.put("dis#font", largeFont);
```

Then you would need to override things like `Button` e.g.:

```
h.put("Button.font", largeFont);
h.put("Button.sel#font", largeFont);
h.put("Button.press#font", largeFont);
h.put("Button.dis#font", largeFont);
```

The simpler alternative would be to load the underlying theme:

```
Map<String, Object> themeHash = (Map<String, Object>)theme.getTheme("Theme");
for(String k : themeHash.keySet()) {
   if(k.endsWith("font")) {
       themeHash.put(k, largeFont);
   }
}
UIManager.getInstance().setThemeProps(h);
Display.getInstance().getCurrent().refreshTheme();
```